# Installing the debug apk shows up as two apps?

Tags: java, android

So I am very new to android programming and I was installing a basic app I just built on my android device and I find that it always seems to install two "instances" of the app ? Here is a screenshot of what I am looking at [The two instances are of the SR520 app] :

[image]

I did some research and it seems like it could be due to the android manifest file but I am not exactly sure what I should change in it. This is what my manifest file looks like

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">



        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Some suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I guess I needed to delete this section

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

That fixed the issue.